# Stop scroll momentum after animated scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, momentum

I am building a website and would like to lock to certain content once passed a threshold. I am using a Jquery animated scrollTop to slide the content into place, and it is working well enough, however I have a momentum problem.

If I scroll slowly when I hit my threshold, all goes according to plan, and the content locks into position, however If I swipe my touch pad more aggressively, I pass the threshold, the scrollTop works, however once it has resolved the window will continue to scroll, making it so my content is not locked in the position I would like.

I haven't be able to find any way to access the scroll events momentum that would enable to nullify it. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not using highcharts for anything on the site. I don't understand you comment.

Comment: Sorry I replied to the wrong question.